# How to output 2 excel files from a single crystal report rpt file

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

The requirement is that for a given set of date parameters I want to to output a premium and a tax excel separately. Currently i have 2 separate rpt files to generate the premium file and tax file. I am thinking to merge both of them and run 1 report only as the data between both files is linked by transaction id.Please advise if that is possible.
Note - I only use Crystal Report V14.0.4 to create the rpt file and don't have the .net assembly to do it through programming.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with Crystal Designer alone.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please advise if there is any other way to achieve this